# Connect to Git Repository in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

I'm having a real issue connecting to a git repository in Jenkins. I'm using Jenkins 2.121.3 which has removed the functionality to use a key from the ~/.ssh/ directory on the Jenkins master.

I have generated a private/public key pair and added the contents of the key to the Jenkins credential. I have uploaded the public key to our BitBucket server for the required user.

Logging on to the Jenkins master I can successfully connect and clone the repository

```
sudo su - jenkins -s /bin/bash
git clone ssh://git@git.ourbitbucketserver/group/repo.git
```

However, whenever I try and set up the git plugin in Jenkins I get the following error

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h 
ssh://git@git.ourbitbucketserver/group/repo.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

We have a different Jenkins instance running on an older version that allows us to load a key from the Jenkins master and this is connecting to the same server with no issues, so I don't think it's anything to do with the configration of the Git server and as we can successfully clone the repository if we SSH to the Jenkins master I can't see it being an issue with the key pair.

Has anybody else had issues inputting the private key directly?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use the github address `https://github.com/ourbitbucketserver/repo` rather than the `git@git` address?

Comment: We're not allowed to use the https endpoints unfortunately, so they're disabled globally (we're using a self hosted version of BitBucket Server, not GitHub)

Comment: any update on this? trying to solve something similar.